# Trying to query between dates with PHP Parse.com

Tags: php, database, parse-platform

I am fairly new to parse.com. basically in summary I am trying to create a query that will show the number of records between 2 dates, in the example below I am actually querying the 14th specifically.

My expected result is 5, however it will always give me 0, regardless?

Overall I have 93 records in the table between the 12th & 14th, even when changing the date range it still gives me only 0, which suggests to me that it is perhaps the date format I have put opposed to the query?

Also, I have changed the ClientID & Key but these are correct in the original code as my other queries are successful.

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';


session_start();
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseObject;

ParseClient::initialize('CLIENTID', 'KEY');

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

$startDate =  '2015-12-14T00:00:00.000Z';
$endDate =  '2015-12-14T23:59:00.000Z';


$query = new ParseQuery("CountTable");
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $startDate);
$query->lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $endDate);
$count = $query->count();
// The count request succeeded. Show the count
echo "Only " . $count . " Results.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this and not getting anywhere, instead of doing a Start & From date I have settled for the date() function & formatted it in the same way as Parse.com

```
$parseDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
$sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

I have then stipulated how many days back I need for each result:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("CountTable");
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $sevenDaysAgo);
$count = $query->count();
// The count request succeeded. Show the count
echo "Only " . $count . " Results.";
```

Comment: I converted my date into the format of parse database. I want to get all data between two dates. I am using the following code. But it is not working..  `$fd=date('Y-m-d\T00:00:00.000\Z', strtotime($fdate));                
                $td=date('Y-m-d\T23:59:59.000\Z', strtotime($tdate));               
                $query = new ParseQuery("Bookings");
                $query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt",$fd);
                $query->lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt",$td);
                $results = $query->find();`

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you can also use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to handle this. You can use the same timestamps for the DateTime as the date() function, and it provides some more built-in functionality for comparing dates, among other things.  It also has the advantage that you can compare and save Parse's Dates directly with DateTime, you don't have to convert them to string or anything like that.  For example (re-using some of your code)

```
$startDate = new DateTime(); //Has current date and time
$startDate->modify("-2 months");
$endDate = new DateTime();
$endDate->modify("-7 days");
$query = new ParseQuery("CountTable");
$query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $startDate);
$query->lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $endDate);
$count = $query->count();
// The count request succeeded. Show the count
echo "Only " . $count . " Results.";
```

Comment: I think that would be the normal way of doing it if I wasn't taking from parse.com, but because parse takes it as: Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u I don't think that method works, I did try it & also tried to format it too, but couldn't get it to work. In the end I used: date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', strtotime('-7 days')); and that seems to be working fine :)